In 68k assembler, when reading the program counter, do you get the address of the currently executing instruction or a later address?
I'm trying to understand some Motorola 68000 assembler code, and I'm getting tripped up by instructions that use the program counter. My confusion is about the effective value of the program counter actually is for any instruction that uses it.
In some places, I'm reading that PC is the address of the currently executing instruction. That is, the address of the first byte of that instruction.
In other places, I'm reading that PC is the address of the next instruction. So if the current instruction being executed is six bytes long, then PC will be the address of the current instruction plus 6.
In still other places, I'm reading that PC's value is the address of the current instruction plus two.
Can anyone help me clear up this confusion? This ought to be well defined. Which one is it?

Consult the manual. Generally PC points to the first extension word of the instruction.

@Jester Thanks, that makes it clear. Feel free to submit that as an answer.

For a branch instruction, the offset is from the start of the next instruction, so for example BRA 0 is effectively a NOP.

Just to make that clear: On the 68000, there is no way to directly read the PC. You could try something like lea.l 0(pc),aX, but that's rejected by many assemblers as "0" is the wrong relocation type (and also not a very useful instruction).
